# 20-second response when using G-WAN /?noheaders.c

Tags: http-headers, browser, latency, g-wan

When I enter the URL `http://localhost:8080/?noheaders.c` in a Web browser, G-WAN seems to be blocking during 20 seconds before responding, whatever the browser (IE, Chrome, or Firefox).

- What is causing this?
- How can we avoid that?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this?

This has nothing to do with G-WAN: this is an HTTP protocol issue.

The `noheaders.c` script demonstrates how to generate a `JSON` reply *without HTTP headers*. This reply is supposed to be fetched by `Javascript` code running in the browser, see the `comet.c` example for an illustration.

When the *"Content-Length"* `HTTP header` is present, browsers don't have to wait more than the time needed to load the *specified amount of data*.

The *lack* of a *"Content-Length"* `HTTP header` is forcing Internet Browsers to guess when to stop waiting for more data (they wait for a while, without displaying anything, and then, after a timeout, they display everything they have received).

> How can we avoid that?

The mechanism is explained in [this other example](http://gwan.com/source/stream3.c) using streaming and the chunked encoding to prevent the browser from blocking.

No *"Content-Length"* is provided because here the length is not known in advance. The chunked-encoding tells browsers that, until they receive and End-Of-Reply marker, they should read more data.